# TFS 2017 workitem search indexing issue

Tags: elasticsearch, tfs

We are using TFS 2017 update 3 (15.117.27024.0) with elasticsearch 2.4.1

Problem:
Trying to find a workitem by word/phrase:

```
"execution": found 398 results
"execution policy": found 10 results
"One or more hosts are not enabled by filter": "indexing your account data" message.
"enabled by filter":"indexing your account data" message.
"enabled by": 22 results
```

What have we tried:
we reconfigured search by deleting search feature, deleting elasticsearch service and deleting cache.

What is the problem? According to logs tfs does not indexing new items.

So is there any wayto fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For TFS 2017 on-premises, Code Search includes **Elasticsearch** and will be configured on a server running TFS 2017. Work Item Search is now also relying on this functionality.

So, firstly make sure the **elasticsearch** service is running on the server where Search is configured. Then try to uninstall the Code search extension and install it again from local extensions gallery, then check if that works.

If that still not work, then you can try [Resetting Search Index](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tapas_sahoos_blog/2017/09/11/resetting-search-index-in-team-foundation-server/)

Refer to below articles for more information on Search Indexing:

- [Monitoring Search Indexing Progress and Completion in Team
  Foundation Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tapas_sahoos_blog/2017/09/13/monitoring-search-indexing-progress-and-completion-in-team-foundation-server/)
- [Code & Work Item Search for TFS 2017 – Troubleshooting](https://web.archive.org/web/20200921102834/https://intovsts.net/2017/11/12/code-work-item-search-for-tfs-2017-troubleshooting/)

Comment: @Alexey Soloviev Have you resolved the issue? any update?